# SimpleInjector Container.Verify() with HTTP context-scoped dependency

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have the following basic SI registration in an ASP.NET WebApi project.

## Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
    {
        options
            .AddAspNetCore()
            .AddControllerActivation();
    });

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddScoped<Work>(services =>
    {
        var traceId = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        // ...
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.ApplicationServices.UseSimpleInjector(container);
    // ...
    container.Verify();
}

private readonly Container container = new Container();
```

## The Problem

`Container.Verify()` attempts to resolve a `Work` instance, whose factory delegate successfully resolves an `IHttpContextAccessor` but its `HttpContext` is `null` because there is no current HTTP call on startup. **Therefore the code dies with a null-reference exception.**

I don't think there is anything we can do except guard against `null` but that goes against my taste in this context:

- why would I do that when I know for a fact that this factory delegate should only be called during an HTTP call?
- what exactly do I do if my HTTP-scoped dependency is `null`? Sure, return a fake BUT how do I detect that it's `null` for good reason and not because my web infrastructure is dying somehow?

I can't see a good solution. What do you do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote extensively about this problem in the past. Your `HttpContext` and its `TraceIdentifier` are runtime data and runtime data should be kept out of the construction of your object graphs. See for instance [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

What the correct solution in your particular case is, is hard to say, because it depends on the details of what you are trying to construct, but the article gives some pointers.

Comment: Thanks, passing the `HttpContextAccessor` to the object under construction did it in this case.